# How to bind AfterTextchanged of EditText using MvxBind

Tags: android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, mvxbind

I would like to know how can I bind listeners of EditText to ViewModel via MvxCommad and ICommand/IMvxCommand

In the below layout, I want to send/push the Editable object which contain the user input to the ViewModel to apply some logic.

I managed to bind button clicks to ViewModel using MvxBind. But i did not find any way to bind AfterTextchanged of EditText?

**EditText**:

mvxBind="AftertextChanged onAfterTextChanged"

Answer (score 0):

`AftertextChanged` should be `AfterTextChanged`.

Additionally, the current implementation of the [built in MvvmCross binding](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross/Platforms/Android/Binding/Target/MvxTextViewTextTargetBinding.cs) relies on AfterTextChanged to bind back the value of the current Text to the ViewModel after it is changed.

Comment: So do you think the attribute added above is correct orshouldbe modified....would you please provide an example

Comment: Sure, first what is your goal for wanting to binds the after text changed event?